# Turn off show search on desktop right site with Fn + Right arrow

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

In 16.04 LTS, when I press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> screen brightness reduces (good) but also, a search box shows at the bottom (don't like); how can I turn off that search box?

[image: Example of unwanted search box at bottom right]